# Dynamic combobox-listbox-drop-down using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, drop-down-menu, forms

Want to populate dynamically combobox-listbox-drop-down using javascript.

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
var select = document.createElement("select");
var option = document.createElement("option");
```

My HTML Code:-

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Dynamically populating drop down, combobox, list box using JavaScript</TITLE>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript" src="config.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY style="font-family: sans-serif">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Combo box</legend>
            Add to Combo: <input type="text" name="txtCombo" id="txtCombo"/>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addCombo()">
            <br/>
            Combobox: <select name="combo" id="combo"></select>
        </fieldset>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

My Javascript:-

```
function addCombo(a, b) {
    var textb = document.getElementById("txtCombo");
    var combo = document.getElementById("combo");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = textb.value;
    option.value = textb.value;
    if {
        combo.add(option, null); //Standard
    }catch(error) {
        combo.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
}
```

Now still its not working is there any issue in the code? Do I am missing something?

Comment: What is not working? Is there a specific problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your function to get this thing done, there is an issue in syntex:-

Change your Javascript to this:-

```
function addCombo() {
    var textb = document.getElementById("txtCombo");
    var combo = document.getElementById("combo");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = textb.value;
    option.value = textb.value;
    try {
        combo.add(option, null); //Standard
    }catch(error) {
        combo.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
}
```

With ***catch*** you need to use ***try***
And you don't need to to put anything in the function **()**

Answer (score 2):

in your javascript code change `if` to `try`